# Spring Kafka RecoveryCallback migration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka 2.X and now want to migrate to 3.0

Currently:

I have a listener container factory setup for retry functionality only, where I am setting up recovery like below:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> retryConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

    // Configure the RetryTemplate
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    // Configure your retry policy, backoff policy, and any other necessary options
    // retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(...);
    // retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(...);

  
    RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor = new RetryOperationsInterceptor();
    interceptor.setRetryOperations(retryTemplate);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

    
    RecoveryCallback<Object> recoveryCallback = context -> {
        

        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = (ConsumerRecord<?, ?>)        context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD);
        System.out.println("Recovery callback invoked for record: " + record.value());


     


    Acknowledgment acknowledgment = (Acknowledgment)              context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT);
        
        System.out.println("Recovery callback invoked for record: " + record.value());
        
        
        if (acknowledgment != null) {
            // Manually acknowledge the record
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }


        return null; 
    };
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(recoveryCallback);

    // Other configuration options for the factory
    return factory;
}
```

Now using kafka spring version 3.0 how can I achieve the same thing ?

I refered to official documentation but it couldnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a `DefaultErrorHandler` with its `BackOff` and `ConsumerRecordRecoverer` options: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html#default-eh.

So, instead of that `factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);` and `factory.setRecoveryCallback(recoveryCallback);` you have to use  `factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(...));`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see the possible solution in the reference you sent. However, I am more confused that how can I acknowledge as I acknowledged in my current recover method ?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. See `DefaultErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered()`

Comment: @ArtemBilan, The above link is dead. Can you please update the latest one if you have it handy?